# When trying to delete a user I'm getting "You do not have the permission required to perform this operation" on my AWS Educate Account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created an AWS Educate account with my university email.

I tried creating an IAM user and it said user created with errors. I did not document the errors.

Then when I tried to delete the created user, I get this error.

```
You need permissions
You do not have the permission required to perform this operation. Ask your administrator to add permissions. Learn more
User: arn:aws:sts::<id>:assumed-role/vocstartsoft/user271512=<university_email_address> is not authorized to perform: iam:DeleteLoginProfile on resource: user <user_name> with an explicit deny
```

What should I do?

Comment: Yes looks like you do not have permission to delete IAM user. you should talk to your administrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Educate Starter Accounts are very limited. You have only basic level of permissions as listed below:

- [AWS Services Supported with AWS Educate Starter Account](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf)

Operation that you are trying to perform `DeleteLoginProfile` is **explicitly denied**, which means that AWS Educate does not allow it.

The only think you can do is to contact **AWS Educate support** if such permissions are required for your assignment or exercise. But it is still unlikely they will allow it.

If you are student, you can contact your **educator** as well. If you are an educator yourself on AWS Educate, you have more options, such as using different class room which may allow such operation or use your personal account.